# finding and printing the line which contains the test string

Tags: python, regex

i have a text file(.txt) with these contents:

```
Active nodes=225785 elements=171665
Running protocol file all_in_one.prot"
Error reading input protocol file
20 coincident elements
Set 999 created (20 elements)
All 171665 elements are suitable
Error reading input protocol file
No nodes deleted in SHOW
No elements displayed
Active nodes=225785 elements=171665
Structure disintegrates
Set >ECHCON-Decay< consists of 164361 elements
```

now my task is to find out the string "elements are suitable" and then if the string is found i need to print the line in which it was found. can i use re module for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you don't need to.

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    if 'elements are suitable' in line:
      print line
```

Comment: yeah thankx it works but is this suited for files with large data @ ignacio

Comment: If you need it to be performant then why aren't you using grep in the first place?

Comment: ok i don't know about grep in python can you tell me how to use it here

Comment: You wouldn't use grep in Pyhon.

Comment: okk you mean to use it by shell... then i did it already....i just want to know about re module